# how to work with drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

i am new to drupal and it is irritating me. i have mastered wordpress and SMF forum software to a near expert level. but drupal as well as joomla have made the admin interfaces so totally confusing i wish there was an answer available for me to use and drop them altogether.

i cant get the slide show to show up on the front page or any other page. i cant find in there a sufficient means of manipulating the content blocks and logging and nav blocks. i am not new to computers and programming, and if this was a programming problem, i probably would have fixed it by now, but the interface is so confusing i cant get the site to do anything im wanting it to do.

i have looked at several tutorials that dont help at all. i found out about a part time job my company is offering and i know for fact i can do it if i can get past the fact that the admin interface is a maze of confusion.

theme demo - http://adaptivethemes.com/demos/atcommerce/

my test - http://tse.myfewclicks.com/drupal/

i beg anyone willing to help. i need to have something presentable, at least a good taste by monday. i could have already been done with it with SMF or wordpress, but they are the wrong type of software for the job.

please help someone.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you may have solved your problem.  I followed your link and the image rotator was working.

About the only difference was that on the AT demo site I was able to click the dots at the lower right hand corner to select the image I wanted whereas on your test site I was unable to do so.